# Composition of Permutations

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose that

$$\sigma = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\ 2 & 7 & 4 & 1 & 6 & 5 & 3   \end{pmatrix}$$

$$\tau = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\ 6 & 2 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 7 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $$

$$\mu = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\ 4 & 1 & 3 & 2 & 6 & 8 & 5 & 7 \end{pmatrix}$$

Compute $\tau\mu\sigma^{-1}$

Workings:

$\sigma = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\ 2 & 7 & 4 & 1 & 6 & 5 & 3   \end{pmatrix}$

$\sigma^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\ 4 & 1 & 7 & 3 & 6 & 5 & 3  \end{pmatrix}$

Now I only know how to do the composition of permutations if they are of the same size. Not different sizes.

So I don't know how $\mu\sigma^{-1}$ is supposed to be computed.

If I were to guess

$\mu\sigma^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 &5 & 6 & 7 \\ 2 & 4 & 5 & 3 & 8 & 6 & 3\end{pmatrix}$

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Break your permutations into disjoint cycles. Start from left to right. Pick $1$ and see to what number it is mapped by the first cycle, then to what number this result is mapped by the second cycle et cetera. Take the last result as inpunt for the next iteration. If you come back to an input you already used, take a number you did not use so far. At the end you have used all numbers from $1$ to $8$- Note that a number which does not occur in a permutation is mapped to itself by that permutation.

Comment: The usual convention is to extend the smaller permutations, in this case by $\pmatrix{8\\8}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before multiplying, convert the smaller permutations to the size of the larger:
$$\sigma = \pmatrix{1&2&3&4&5&6&7&\color{blue}8\\2&7&4&1&6&5&3&\color{blue}8}$$
$$\sigma^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\ 4 & 1 & 7 & 3 & 6 & 5 & \color{red}2 & 8\end{pmatrix}$$

Then proceed as usual.
$$\mu\sigma^{-1} = \pmatrix{1&2&3&4&5&6&7&\color{red}8\\2&4&5&3&8&6&\color{red}1&\color{red}7}$$
(red here is an error in your post).

Comment: If the permutations given in the beginning by the OP are correct, it should be $\mu\sigma^{-1}(4)=3$ and $\mu\sigma^{-1}(7)=1$ so those two should be interchanged in your answer ...

Comment: Alright thanks for the help.

Comment: @String I copied an error in $\sigma^{-1}$ from the OP. Fixing.

Answer (score 1):

As a combination of AlexR's and Curiosity's comments:
$$
\sigma=(1\ 2\ 7\ 3\ 4)(5\ 6)
$$
so in particular $\sigma$ does nothing to $8$ and
$$
\sigma^{-1}=(4\ 3\ 7\ 2\ 1)(5\ 6)
$$
Furthermore, $\mu=(1\ 4\ 2)(5\ 6\ 8\ 7)$. So we have
$$
\begin{align}
\mu\sigma^{-1}&=(1\ 4\ 2)(5\ 6\ 8\ 7)(4\ 3\ 7\ 2\ 1)(5\ 6)\\
&=(1\ 2\ 4\ 3\ 5\ 8\ 7)\\
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\
2&4&5&3&8&6&1&7
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
$$
In your original post you made the error of letting $\sigma^{-1}(7)=3$ whereas it should be $\sigma^{-1}(7)=2$. This error is found again later on in your suggestion for $\mu\sigma^{-1}$.

Comment: Okay I see thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Writing $\sigma$, $\tau$, $\mu$ as products of disjoint cycles, you have:

- $\sigma=(1,2,7,3,4)(5,6)$
- $\tau=(1,6,7)(3,5)$
- $\mu=(1,4,2)(5,6,8,7)$

Now proceed as usual for compositions of permutations....